# What causes the Chrome wants to permanently store large data message?

Tags: google-chrome, offline-caching

I'm trying to figure out which storage mechanism causes the

> wants to permanently store large data

message on chrome. Is it indexdb, filesystem api, offline storage api or something else? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely, the HTML5 Filesystem API will cause this the first time it is invoked from within JavaScript (`window.webkitStorageInfo.requestQuota`).  Subsequently, for the same URL, you will not be prompted unless you have cleared the cache (`chrome://settings/cookies`).The prompt can be avoided by starting Chrome with the command line option:

```
--unlimited-storage
```

However, there are security risks inherent with this. [Here](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/filesystem/) is an excellent HTML5 Filesystem tutorial by its author/inventor Eric Bidelman which covers the entire API.